# Is Stack Overflow a good place for this question? If not, where should I put it?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I have a question about the file `UAService.exe`. Would Stack Overflow be an appropriate place to ask my question, or is there another Stack Exchange site where I should ask it instead?

My question is roughly:

> What happens if I modify or remove the `UAService.exe` binary file? What
>   effects would deletion/modification of the file would have on my
>   system?

When i ask the question on whichever site turns out to be best, I will hash it out more, and be specific in what I am asking.

Comment: What is your question? This *could* be on-topic on Stack Overflow. But depending on the question, it may be better suited for SuperUser.

Comment: We'd need more details to be able to answer this- One of the easiest ways to tell is to quote the question you want to ask, or paraphrase it really.

Comment: What research have you attempted on that so far? are you interested in what that file is / contains / does?

Comment: I have googled it several times, with different terms. All I ever got was sites that advertise "Security Task Manager" and do "Security ratings"

Comment: But what do you need from/with this file? In which programming task is that file blocking you? And where is that file located? In which folder?

Comment: I agree with the above that SuperUser may be the more appropriate location. As far as I see, you haven't given enough context to convince me this is a programming question. 

I searched "remove UAService.exe binary file" and found this: http://www.file.net/process/uaservice.exe.html , (could be helpful and save a post).

As @Rene is suggesting, you'll need to offer much more context, no matter which site you choose to submit this question to.

Comment: @Trobbins Finally, somebody answered my question. So what I am hearing is that it does not go in SO, but rather SuperUser?

Comment: Should be noted @Amal had already suggested SuperUser. 

Down and dirty, if you have a specific programming question, it can go in SO. Otherwise, perhaps head over to SuperUser and check the [on-topic questions guide](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt there would be any site happy to have a question that read:

> What happens if I modify or remove the UAService.exe binary file?"
>    I am looking for the effects deletion/modification of the file would have on my system

What is missing is why you want that file removed? Which diagnosis lead to such firm belief that deleting was an option? And in what context is that executable used by you?

If you add those details, and assuming this is not related to programming, you might first ask on the [meta of Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/) if such a question would fly there.

In its current form I would say it shouldn't be asked on any site

Comment: Thank you. I was definitely planning to hash the question out a lot more.